# Handling Http requests

Tags: node.js, reactjs, localhost, fetch-api

I'm very much new to backend development and integrating front end to the backend. My issue is that while trying to send a post request I get a 404 status code `POST http://localhost:5000/api/data 404 (Not Found)`
The code on my front end is:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/data')
    .then(res => { return res.json() })
    .then((data) => {
      setData(data)
      setDatarecieved(true)
    })
  }, [])


  const clickHandler = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/data', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "id": 5,
          "name":"test"
        })
      })
    }
```

Note that the first part of it where works flawlessly. My issue is limited to the post req.

The code in my back end goes as follows:

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const data = require('./data.json');

const cors=require("cors");
const corsOptions ={
   origin:'*',
   credentials:true,
   optionSuccessStatus:200,
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions)) 

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.get('/api/data',(req,res)=>{
    res.send(data);
});

app.get('/api/data/:id',(req,res)=>{
    const x=data[req.params.id];
    res.send(data);
});

app.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log('Server is running on port 5000');
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: To handle a POST request to `/api/data`, you should have something like `app.post('/api/data', (req, res) => { ... })`

Comment: I’m not very experienced with express, but is there anywhere that defines the CRUD method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boss it looks like your looking for this

```
 app.post('/api/data',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body)
        res.send(req.body);
    });
```

Comment: Please accept this answer so that it can help others

Comment: I'm afraid the error 404 persists. Is there something else that I need to include on the front end to post data on the backend?

Comment: Using put works but post doesn't

Answer (score 1):

you don't have a route for post method in your backend

Comment: I'm afraid not. Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You need to add a handler for post route to your backend and access the posted data through req.body, like this: app.post('/api/data',(req,res)=>{ 
    res.send(req.body);
});

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks! It was a silly question in retrospect xD

Comment: The issue still persists. What else could be the cause of this?

Comment: More replies are on the other thread